# Puppet - how to provision a user on the guest machine with the same username as the user on the host machine

Tags: vagrant, puppet, provisioning

**How can I configure puppet to provision a user on the guest machine with a username that matches the username of the user on the host machine who provisions the guest?** *(Using puppet apply, not server/master)*

```
$ puppet --version
3.4.3
$ vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.7.2
```

**This is what I've tried so far:**

Following the instructions in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16733991/328275) I tried to use vagrant/puppet to create a user account on the guest machine which matches the user account on the host machine. But ultimately, it didn't work. Instead of getting the host username, a "$user_name" user was created.

*Vagrantfile:*

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "npalm/mint17-amd64-cinnamon"
  config.vm.hostname = "dev-env"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.name = "dev-env"
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1280"]
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provisioning/shell/apt-update.sh"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provisioning/shell/puppet.sh"
  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.facter = {
      "user_name" => ENV['USER']
    }
    puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
    puppet.manifests_path = "provisioning/puppet/manifests"
    puppet.module_path = "provisioning/puppet/modules"
  end
end
```

*provisioning/shell/apt-update.sh:*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install -y aptitude
```

*provisioning/shell/puppet.sh:*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo aptitude install -y puppet
```

*provisioning/puppet/manifests/default.pp:*

```
user { '$user_name':
  ensure  => 'present',
  comment => 'developer account',
  home    => '/home/$user_name',
  shell   => '/bin/bash',
  uid     => 643
}
->
file{'$user_name home':
  ensure => 'directory',
  path => '/home/$user_name',
  owner => '$user_name',
  group => '$user_name'
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
##############
# Host Machine
##############
$ whoami
axiopisty

###############
# Guest Machine
###############
$ ls -la /home/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root       4096 Dec 17 23:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root       root       4096 Sep 28 20:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 $user_name $user_name 4096 Dec 17 23:41 $user_name
drwxr-xr-x 13 vagrant    vagrant    4096 Sep 28 20:42 vagrant
```

**Expected Output**

```
##############
# Host Machine
##############
$ whoami
axiopisty

###############
# Guest Machine
###############
$ ls -la /home/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root       4096 Dec 17 23:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root       root       4096 Sep 28 20:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 axiopisty  axiopisty  4096 Dec 17 23:41 axiopisty
drwxr-xr-x 13 vagrant    vagrant    4096 Sep 28 20:42 vagrant
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puppet will not resolve variable names when its simple quoted. To make sure [interpolation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_variables.html#interpolation)  of your variable names is done, you must use `"`; so the following in your puppet file will work

```
user { $user_name:
  ensure  => 'present',
  comment => 'developer account',
  home    => "/home/$user_name",
  shell   => '/bin/bash',
  uid     => 643
}
->
file{"$user_name home":
  ensure => 'directory',
  path  => "/home/$user_name",
  owner => "$user_name",
  group => "$user_name"
}
```